Не срабатывает изменение ширины экрана
Есть компонент , в случае если ширина экрана меньше , то должны отрабатывать другие стили
но это работает только в случае , если самому в ручную обновить окно браузера


 const onCheckMobile = () => {
      setIsMobile(window.innerWidth <= 992);
      // console.log('resize', window.innerWidth);
    };

    const onScrollUpdate = () => {
      currentScrollYPosition.current = window.scrollY;
      if (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight > document.body.scrollHeight - 40 && onceUpdate) {
        setParams(prev => ({ ...prev, page: prev.page + 1 }));
        onceUpdate = false;
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener('touchmove', onScrollUpdate);
    document.addEventListener('scroll', onScrollUpdate);
    document.addEventListener('resize', onCheckMobile);
    onCheckMobile();
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('resize', onCheckMobile);
      document.removeEventListener('touchmove', onScrollUpdate);
      document.removeEventListener('scroll', onScrollUpdate);
      onChangeDebounce.cancel();
    };
  }, []);




Есть компонент в твоем "примере" нет никакого компонента...

Так же нужно помнить что рендер компонента инициируется изменением пропсов или изменением стейта. Если у тебя рендера не происходит - значит ничего из этого не произошло. Либо ты наворотил там такого, что алгоритм не выполняет желаемого...

Просто надо было подписаться через window , а не через document
и все заработало
